# Do I understand the semantics of std::memory_order correctly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers, stdatomic, memory-model

[c++reference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) states about `memory_order::seq_cst`:

> A load operation with this memory order performs an acquire operation, a store performs a release operation, and read-modify-write performs both an acquire operation and a release operation, plus a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order.

[ Q1 ]: Does this mean that the order goes straight down through **every operation of all (others + this) atomic_vars with memory_order::seq_cst?**

[ Q2 ]: And `release` , `acquire` and `rel_acq` are not included in "single total order" ?

I understood that `seq_cst` is equivalent to the other three with write, read and write_read operation, but I'm confused about whether `seq_cst` can order other atomic_vars too, not only the same var.

Comment: you can see the [detail about `seq_cst` below](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering)

Comment: @appleapple thank u. I think I understood right, but I'm not great at english and I have concern that maybe I am wrong. So I wanna check am I right. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cppreference is only a summary of the C++ standard, and sometimes its text is less precise. The actual standard draft makes it clear: The [final C++20 working draft N4681](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf) states in atomics.order, par. 4 (p. 1525):

> There is a single total order S on all `memory_order::seq_cst` operations, including fences, that satisfies the following constraints [...]

This clearly says **all** `seq_cst` operations, not just all operations on a particular object.

And notes 6 and 7 further down emphasize that the order does not apply to weaker memory orders:

> 6 [Note: We do not require that S be consistent with “happens before” (6.9.2.1). This allows more efficient
> implementation of memory_order::acquire and memory_order::release on some machine architectures.
> It can produce surprising results when these are mixed with memory_order::seq_cst accesses. — end note]
>
> 7 [Note: memory_order::seq_cst ensures sequential consistency only for a program that is free of data races
> and uses exclusively memory_order::seq_cst atomic operations. Any use of weaker ordering will invalidate
> this guarantee unless extreme care is used. In many cases, memory_order::seq_cst atomic operation

Comment: thanks ! I should read standard doc to make more cleary about side effetcs. thanks.

Comment: I added a link to the draft (which had a different number -- 4680 was the coroutine extension proposal). It may be of interest also to other people curious about this question.

Answer (score 1):

I find this part incomplete:

> A load operation with this memory order performs an acquire operation,
> a store performs a release operation, and read-modify-write performs
> both an acquire operation and a release operation, plus a single total
> order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the
> same order.

If those things (release store, acquire loads, and a total store order) were actually sufficient to give sequential consistency, that would imply that release and acquire operations on their own would be more strongly ordered than the actually are.

Let's have a look at the following counter example:

```
CPU1:
   a = 1 // release store
   int r1 = b // acquire load
```

Then based on the above definition for SC (and the known properties sequential consistency must have to fit the name), I would presume that the store of `a` and the load of `b` can't be reordered:

- we have a release-store and an acquire-load
- we (can) have a total order over all loads/stores

So we have satisfied the above definition for sequential consistency.

But a release-store followed by an acquire-load to a different address can be reordered. The canonical example would be Dekker's algorithm. Therefor the above definition for SC is broken because it is missing that memory order needs to preserve the program order.  Apart from a compiler messing things up, the typical cause of this violation would be store buffers which most modern CPUs have can cause an older store to be reordered with a newer load to a different address.

The single total order is a different concern than CPU local instruction reordering as you can get with e.g. store buffers. It effectively means that there is some moment where an operation takes effect in the memory order and nobody should be able to disagree with that. The standard litmus test for this is the independent reads of independent writes (IRIW):

```
CPU1:
   A=1
CPU2:
   B=1
CPU3:
   r1=A
   [LoadLoad]
   r2=B
CPU4:
   r3=B
   [LoadLoad]
   r4=A
```

So could it be that CPU3 and CPU4 see the stores to different addresses in different orders? If the answer is yes, then no total order over the load/stores exist.

Another cause of a not having a total order over the loads/stores is store to load forwarding (STLF).

```
CPU1:
   A=1
   r1=A
   r2=B

CPU2:
   B=1
   r3=B
   r4=A
```

It is possible that r1=1, r2=0, r3=1 and r4=0?

On the X86 this is possible due to store to load forwarding. So if CPU1 does a store of A followed by a load of A, then the CPU must look in the store buffer for value of A. This causes the store of A not to be atomic; the local CPU can see the store early and the consequence is no total order over the loads/stores exist.

So instead of having a total order over all load/stores, it is reduced to a total order over the stores and this is how the X86 gets its name for its memory model (Total Store Order).

[edit]
Made some clarifications. I cleaned up some text and cleaned up the original example because it was misleading.

Comment: The question is quoting a paragraph that describes `memory_order::seq_cst`.  You weakened it to `memory_order::release` and `memory_order::acquire`.  The "single total order" property is only a feature of seq_cst; that's why it's so expensive because even pure stores have to drain the store buffer (at least before seq_cst loads, like on ARMv8).  The point of that paragraph is to state that `store(seq_cst)` is a release operation like `store(release)`, *as well as* being part of the total order.  Not to say that all release operations have that property.

Comment: There is a point to be made here, though, which is that the cppreference summary of it fails to say that the modification order agreed on by all observers is compatible with program-order in each thread.  And that both loads and stores are part of the total order formed by seq_cst operations.  The paragraph you quoted *doesn't* imply no StoreLoad reordering, only x86 TSO.  (*observe all **modifications** in the same order.*)  Yes, seq_cst does imply the existence of a total store order (for seq_cst readers), but when summarizing that point is best left as part of a total order of all ops.

Comment: "There is a point to be made here, though, which is that the cppreference summary of it fails to say that the modification order agreed on by all observers is compatible with program-order in each thread. "

Exactly.

Comment: Also a total order isn't a property of just SC. E.g. IBM 370 also has a total order over all loads and stores, but it allows for older stores to be reordered with newer loads to a different address. Only it doesn't allow for STLF; it requires to store to be made globally visible before a load to the same address can be performed. So total order over the loads/stores + acquire/release will not give SC. You need to have preservation of PO and this is my primary complaint about the above description.

Comment: IDK what you mean by replying "exactly".  Your answer still says "Then based on the above definition, I would presume that the store of a and the load of b can't be reordered:" but that makes no sense because you used `mo_release` and `mo_acquire` so the paragraph you quoted doesn't have anything to say about your code block.  (And as you just discussed for IBM370, what it does say wouldn't prevent StoreLoad reordering, just guarantee that there is *some* total order maybe not compatible with program order.  Actually even weaker since it doesn't mentions loads being part of the total order.)

Comment: So I think you're making your point totally backwards.  You should use `mo_seq_cst` in your code block, and then argue that the definition given *does* allow StoreLoad reordering.  (Because it's basically x86-TSO, not SC).  And that that's something ISO C++ forbids for `seq_cst`, as well as being incompatible with the normal language-independent meaning of sequential consistency.

Comment: My primary point was that the above definition of SC is missing the requirement that the PO needs to be preserved. The example I provided is an illustration why the quoted definition will not give SC.

Comment: So your example is using actual ISO C++ orders (which the reader thus needs to fully understand) to show what the quoted definition would imply if you were to have used `seq_cst` store and load?  That's *not* how your text talks about it.  You talk about the definition quoted implying *that* code you do show not being allowed to reorder.  But even ISO C++ does allow your code to reorder.  Because you didn't use seq_cst.

Comment: There is some useful stuff here re: parts of the question, but until the problems are fixed I'm going to have to downvote because this answer is showing non-`seq_cst` code and saying the opposite of what the quoted problematic text implies if it *were* seq_cst.  It's likely more confusing than helpful to people who don't already understand the definition of ISO C++ `memory_order_seq_cst`, and maybe also of acq and rel.

Comment: Sure. In retrospect it would have been better not to have used the memory_order_acquire and memory_order_release. It would have been better to use the text from the definition; so acquire load and a release store.

Comment: But it's not talking about all acquire operations, it's talking about loads that use `mo_seq_cst`.  *A load operation **with this memory order** performs an acquire operation*.  The problem to point out is that SC store can't reorder with SC release, but the paragraph doesn't say that.  Not that anything it does say is false.

Comment: As you have pointed out yourself, the definition is incomplete. It is missing that an older store can't be reordered with a newer load to a different address since the rest of the ordering requirements are already captured by the acquire-load and store-release. If this is missing you will not get SC, but you will get IBM-370.

Comment: Yes, we both agree the definition isn't complete.  What I'm also trying to point out is that your actual *answer* doesn't say that.  Instead your answer says the definition *is* strong (which is incorrect like you just said), and that `mo_release` and `mo_acquire` violate it (a non-sequitur because non-SC operations don't have to obey the SC rules).

Comment: I have updated the text to not make use of mo_acquire/mo_release since that was a cause of confusion. The argument is an argument by counter example that demonstrates that the above definition is incomplete.

Comment: So when you say *Then based on the above definition for SC, I would presume that the store of a and the load of b can't be reordered:* - you actually mean based on a *normal* definition for SC, not the one given above?  I.e. you meant to say what the definition *should* be guaranteeing, not what it is guaranteeing?  That's not what you wrote.

Comment: (And also, you're still showing pseudocode like `a = 1 // release store` not `// seq-cst store` in your code block.  The problem is the definition only giving a seq_cst store release properties, not if the original source only has a release store.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237743/discussion-between-pveentjer-and-peter-cordes).